# Normal distribution gives negative value

Tags: python, r, normal-distribution

To give some context, I created a model that could predict the age of a person. My dataset is not big, and I have a variance which is not negligible.

I tried plotting the normal distribution of the age, but it gives me negatives values (see the picture) which means it isn't really following a Normal distribution.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of a distribution I can plot the same way (with no negative value) and the hypothesis I need for it to be valid ?

Comment: You cannot, the normal distribution is non null on the [-inf inf] interval

Comment: Congrats, you discovered that age doesnot really follow a normal distribution. You will need to use a different distribution. Personally, I suggest an empirical density function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can seek for a lognormal distribution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 3., 1. # mean and standard deviation

s = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 100, density=True, align='mid')

x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 10000)

pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

       / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))

plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')

plt.axis('tight')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Whilst this is a potential solution, it is not *the* solution.  OP should be aware of the implications of its use.  Does OP's data follow a logNormal distribution?  Do multiplicative errors make sense for their data? Etc, etc.